# pandas contains exact string from a list

Tags: python, pandas

I have 2 dataframes df1 and df2.

I would like to get all rows in df1 that has exact string match in column B of df2
This is df1:

```
df1={"columnA":['apple,cherry','pineple,lemon','banana, pear','cherry, pear, lemon']} 
df1=pd.DataFrame(df1)
```

This is df2:

```
df2={"columnB":['apple','cherry']}
df2=pd.DataFrame(df2)
```

Below code output incorrect result:

```
df1[df1['columnA'].str.contains('|'.join(df2['columnB'].values))]
```

[image]

Pineapple is not supposed to appear as this is not exact match.

How can i get result like this:

[image]

Comment: Could you please post your dataframes as code, so it is easier for us to help you?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Without actual reproducible code it's harder to help you, but I think this should work:

```
words = [rf'\b{string}\b' for string in df2.columnB]
df1[df1['columnA'].str.contains('|'.join(words))]
```

Answer (score 0):

```
df1={"columnA":['apple,cherry','pineple,lemon','banana, pear','cherry, pear, lemon']} 
df1=pd.DataFrame(df1)
    
df2={"columnB":['apple','cherry']}
df2=pd.DataFrame(df2)
```

Larger way of doing it ,but correct and simpler

```
list1=[]
for i in range(0,len(df1)):
    for j in range(0,len(df2)):
        if(df2["columnB"][j] in df1["columnA"][i]):
            list1.append(i)
            break
df=df1.loc[list1]
```

Answer

```
ColumnA
0   apple,cherry
3   cherry, pear, lemon
```

Answer (score -1):

You were very close, but you will need to apply the word-operator of regex:

`df1[df1['columnA'].str.contains("\b(" + '|'.join(df2['columnB'].values) + ")\b")]`

This will look for the complete words.